# Scrollbarwidth prevents document from 100% width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have this view or two columns, one is taking the third of the page and the other is taking 1/3 (the rest of the page). All works fine.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        var height = $(window).height();
        var width = $(document).width();
        var right = (width/3);
        var about = width - right;

        $('#about').height(height);
        $('#events').height(height - (height/2));
        $('#vision').height(height/2);
        $('.inner-menu').height($('#right').height());

        $('#about, #contact').width(about);
        $('#right').width(right);
        $('.inner-menu').width(width/3);
```

When I first load the page, automatically the scrollbar shows up then disappears, and this causes a margin of 17px, I have to resize the browser to have it back to normal...

Is there anyway to prevent this? Since the height always adapts to the window's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I used

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

then use jquery to show it on other screens

```
if (width <= 1024){
    $('html').css({
        "overflow": "visible"
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the scroll bar is showing up because your html is beyond the bounds of the current window. If your code above is fixing that, you could consider hiding the html until your code has executed. the following css will hide it until you are ready:

```
 html {
    display: none;
 }
```

Comment: Still giving me same problem, tried your code and I show it using jquery when document is ready ... but still gives me the same marge ... and it is annoying since when I try to show the menu it shows it off marge >.>

Comment: can i see your code. the css above should hide everything on the page. You should not see anything.

Comment: Yes it hides everything, but after the document is ready i did `$('html').show();`, unless i see no point in hiding everything ...

Comment: Another option would be to find the html element that is causing the scrollbar to appear in the first place, and changing the css so that it is within the length of the window.

Comment: I have used the `overflow:hidden` to hide the scrollbar ... but still same problem, now since I have that 17 added,  I can have the "right" section floated to the left so it will fit as second column but only goes under the first one ...